# How to Append Query in SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, where-clause

How To append SQL Query in where Clause of Stored Procedure???

IN Stored Prcedure I have defined 1 parameter @ViewType, which accepts 1 of 3 value 'Uploaded','Not Uploaded' and 'ALL'. According to the value of ViewType the condition is applied in where caluse (FileType in below query).

Some Select Query

-> if(@ViewType = 'Uploaded')

WHERE ContractNumber=1234 AND DocumentType='VendorContract' AND ID=54 AND FileType IS NOT NULL

->  if(@ViewType = 'Not Uploaded')

WHERE ContractNumber=1234 AND DocumentType='VendorContract' AND ID=54 AND FileType IS NULL

-> 
if(@ViewType = 'ALL')

WHERE ContractNumber=1234 AND DocumentType='VendorContract' AND ID=54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refactor this logic as a single `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    (        
        (@ViewType = 'Uploaded' AND FileType IS NOT NULL) OR
        (@ViewType = 'Not Uploaded' AND FileType IS NULL) OR
        @ViewType = 'ALL'
    ) AND
    ContractNumber = 1234 AND DocumentType = 'VendorContract' AND ID = 54
```